# I'm trying to change 61 to hexadecimal, but I have to get '3D', but I have '313.' What's wrong?

Tags: python, replace

```
def deci_to_any_list():
n0 = input('Enter a number: ')
n = int(n0)
if n>0:
    radix0 = input('Enter a radix: ')
    radix = int(radix0)
    if 1 < radix < 17:
        converted_number = []
        while not int(n/radix) == 0:
            converted_number.append(n % radix)
            n = int(n/radix)
        else:
            converted_number.append(n % radix)
            converted_number.reverse()
            c = ''.join([str(i) for i in converted_number])
            c.replace('10', 'A')
            c.replace('11', 'B')
            c.replace('12', 'C')
            c.replace('13', 'D')
            c.replace('14', 'E')
            c.replace('15', 'F')
            c.replace('16', 'G')
            print(c)
    else:
        print('Wrong input!!')
else:
    print('Wrong input!!')
```

Enter a number: 61
Enter a radix: 16
313

I want to change the entered value from binary to hexadecimal on python. I'm trying to change 61 to hexadecimal, but I have to get '3D', but I have '313.' What's wrong?

Comment: You're not saving the results of your `replace` calls (but your code would be wrong even with that fixed, because those `replace` calls replace things they shouldn't).

Comment: You are uncomfortable with the [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) function?